# What parts are suitable replacements for an Ender 3 Pro?

Tags: extruder, hotend, creality-ender-3, replacement-parts, part-identification

I'm new to 3D printing and I recently got my first 3D printer, an Ender 3 Pro by Creality.

I've tried to find information about the type of nozzles should I look for. I'm trying to find stainless steel nozzles but there are so many models (M7, M8, etc.) and I have no idea what nozzle type I should get.

I've tried searching on Google but the only info I could find is that the extruder is an MK-10.

I am also looking for a heating cartridge for the hot end, but I still cannot find no information about the size that I need (15 mm/20 mm/30 mm). Also looked for info about the heated bed so I know what kind of thermistor I need (I found two types and no clue which one to get).

Where can I find some technical information about these?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I not sure but this might get closed as a shopping question, although, you're looking for the parts list, not exactly where to buy them (or so it seems). Search for MK10 nozzle on Amazon. You should readily find them there. Size on those should be M6x13x6mm. Micro-Swiss HW-NOZ-MK10-04 is one example. I believe you can find most of what you need on Amazon, if for nothing else, finding the parts to buy elsewhere if you don't like Jeff Bezos.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I do not live in the US nor Amazon is available over here, so I need to get them from somewhere like AliExpress. I did search for MK10 nozzle already but I get multiple types (M7, M8) and I do not know what to get.

Comment: You may not have Amazon available for delivery, but you can use them for parts detection! :o)

Comment: Try looking at Chinese suppliers on eBay. FWIW, I've just started using AliExpress, and I find that the search mechanism is terrible, compared to eBay, although AliExpress is often cheaper than eBay

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 IMHO this is not a shopping question, it is a question asking which parts his machine consists off. Considering the different parts that exist and Chinglish texts describing the parts, I can image that there is confusion. See also [this recent meta topic](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/are-shopping-questions-on-topic-for-the-site).

Comment: @0scar It is a list question though. What part does he want information about? I see... nozzle... heater cartridge... heatbed... thermistor... ALL these parts would warrent a separate question like "Which dimensions has the heater cartridge is in an Ender3Pro?" etc.

Comment: @iamroot:  "M7, M8" refers to the metric thread size/gauge.  Regardless of the material type, you need nozzles with same gauge as your block uses.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, indeed I need the M6 nozzle and 20mm heat cartridge as @Greenonline and 0scar suggested!

Comment: I don't think that I helped that much, tbh, but I'm glad that you got an answer. Good luck, and keep visiting this site, if you have any more questions (or answers). :-) BTW, I think that you mean 20mm heater **block**, *not* **cartridge**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ender 3 takes an M6 thread (metric 6 mm diameter). Measurement of stock nozzle shown.

Most sellers will list compatible printers Ender 2, Ender 3, Ender 4, CR-10, CR-10S, CR-10 Mini, CR-10-S4, CR-10-S5, CR-8, CR-7. Will Also Fit Any Other MK10 Heater Blocks.

I recently bought some titanium alloy nozzles as the brass one got closed over after crashing into the glass bed.

[image: Measurement of nozzle in digital calipers]

Comment: OTOH,  brass nozzles are dirt-cheap, so buy a dozen and swap in as needed.

Comment: You get what you pay for. Given my Ender 3 keeps nose diving the bed every now and then, I’d rather have a nozzle that costs 5 times as much and doesn’t need changing :) (I will be getting an ABL).

Comment: Heh ... was just considering a nose dive with a titanium nozzle on a glass bed ... crunch. I think I'd rather get the problem fixed as replacing glass beds I'm sure gets expensive after a bit.

Comment: @Paulster2: Funny you should say that. I switched back to my original Ender 3 bed after switching nozzles, only to gouge a long grove in the bed (after manually levelling)... Ender 3 really needs an ABL.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a single MK10 hotend design. The Chinese aftermarket has mingled the designations.

If it has a [MK10 like Makerbot](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/wanhao-printer-3d/TEdslEknny4) hotend, then the nozzles you are looking for are M7 threads. It appears (see [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7367/5740)) that your hotend is a cloned MK10 and has different dimensions, you have the M6 version.

Quote from link above: (this is about the Makerbot MK10)

> MK10 was a complete change of the hotend. MK10 uses smooth OD thermal
>   barriers with a larger 4mm OD 2mm ID PTFE liner. MK10 also uses M7
>   threads, vs the M6 of all previous models. This is because a 4mm PTFE
>   liner is barely enough metal to make the outer tube with m6 threads.
>   MK10 is completely incompatible with all previous hotend parts. Every
>   part is different. Mk10 still uses MK9 feeder parts.

You could measure your current heat block (the width of the Aluminium block); if you look at the MK10 drawings  of a proper M7 MK10 Makerbot (or derivative) hotend (below) you see that the width of the block is about 19 mm (which would be the length of the heater cartridge).

[image: MK10 Aluminium heater block dimensions]

The CEO of ToyBuilder labs explains the difference between an "MK10" and an MK8 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnI0aeTw9iA):

[image: "MK10" vs. MK8 nozzle]

As can be seen, your nozzle clearly is not an MK10.

Comment: Where did you get the diagram? The ender 3 is a MK10 hotbed but it is an M6 thread. Not M7.

Comment: @GoneCoding A true MK10 (invented by Makerbot) has these dimensions, if not it is a different MK10.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are also correct, I need the M6 nozzles and the 20mm cartridge!

Comment: @iamroot There is a lot of confusion, as there are more MK10 designs around. See e.g. the [difference between an MK8 and an MK10 nozzle](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=2ahUKEwjxqsLarsLeAhUK1hoKHWJvAN0QwqsBMAF6BAgJEAo&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov).